# I need to use themeMyLogin widget

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Should I use theme my login widget? I don't know whether or not I should begin programming it from scratch or there is already a widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just want to [use this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/)?

Comment: yes. I want to have it as a widget. How then??

Comment: The instructions on how to install are here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Managing_Plugins#Installing_Plugins

Comment: And using it as a widget: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-theme-my-login-seperate-template-for-login-page-and-widget